# How do I correct the error 'The Value expression for the field 'Current_EHCP' contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am new to writing reports and have started out on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I have created a report the appears to work in preview but throws up the error above.

The error has appeared since I created the following expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!SEN_Ref.Value="E","Y",nothing)
```

I want this field to show a *Y* if the *SEN_ref* is 'E', otherwise I want the cell to remain blank.

I don't even know if can just ignore the errors (as the report appears to be working) or if I have made a school boy error in my expression!

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What datatype is `SEN_Ref` ?

Comment: Hi,  it's a string.  I'm very new to this.  I think this is what you are asking!  Thank you